# Pax-Exam @Configuration in test classes

Tags: pax-exam

In Pax-exam test classes. We have to provide the configuration as follows. to create the container.

```
@Configuration
public Option[] config() {
    setup();

    return options(
            mavenBundle().artifactId("testng").groupId("org.testng").versionAsInProject(),
            mavenBundle().artifactId("sample1").groupId("sample2").versionAsInProject(),
            mavenBundle().artifactId("sample3").groupId("sample4").versionAsInProject()

}
```

Instead of defining this in every test class, can't we provide a configuration to provision the container?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`ConfigurationFactory` service](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXEXAM4/Configuration+Options). Or simply factor out your options to some static helper method and invoke this from the `@Configuration` method of your tests.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue using Configuration Factory. Thanks.